# Unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir in chrome driver

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am getting below error while running the code. I am using cucumber ruby capybara framework.If there is any solutions please do answer. Thanks a lot.

Error is as below:

> Unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)

Comment: The user account that is running the chromedriver does not have permission to make changes to the Chrome profile directory.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue with chrome drivers. Following are the cases that I found could lead to this issue:

- Missing TEMP or TMP environment variables
- TEMP or TMP is mapped not to local NTFS drive
- Permission issue (if you are using user other than the logged in user)
- TEMP or TMP invalid path

In my case TEMP was mapped to *C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\MyFolder*. So when the Temp folder got cleared, MyFolder folder also got deleted and chromedriver threw "**Unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir**" **. By creating a new folder with name "MyFolder" in Temp folder fixed my issue.**

TEMP and TMP path can be verified at

**My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System settings -> Environment Variables -> Variables used for < your user >**

Or else you can check it by entering "%temp%" in "Run" window.

Its better to check path using both ways because I have seen some cases where temp path set in environment variable and path of folder that opens on executing %temp% command via Run were different.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this work, however, the folder name may not called as myfolder, i tried to key in %temp% in run to make sure what is the missing folder

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix: running IntelliJ as admin solved my problem!

Comment: That is not really an approach to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I met same issue and solved it now.
I checked the path of TEMP dirctory according to many online suggestions.

- Check Environment Variable
- Run command **echo %temp%**

The important thing I found that sometimes the paths are different in above two methods.(I never edited this path before checking it)
In my case:

- Check Environment Variable
  *C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp*
- Run command **echo %temp%**
  *C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\4*

So I checked the Temp directory and there wasn't 4 folder.
I created 4 folder manually in the Temp directory and the issue was solved.
Of course, this is the case of Administrator.
I haven't checked the case of user, but hope it helpful for the case too.